# matplotlib graphs not displaying on tkinter window

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

When I try to graph something with matplotlib in a tkinter window, it simply won't show up. If I remove the tkinter specific part, and just do a basic plt.plot(...) and plt.show() it shows up in my regular text output field. However, in this case I would like it to show up in a tkinter window. I Believe its because I am running this on a mac (macOS 10.12.4), however I cannot figure out how to get it to show up in the tkinter window.

```
import numpy as np
import Tkinter as tk

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = tk.Tk()

fig = plt.figure(1)
t = np.arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
s = np.sin(np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t,s)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
plot_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()

def update():
    s = np.cos(np.pi*t)
    plt.plot(t,s)
    plt.show()

plot_widget.grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(root,text="Update",command=update).grid(row=1, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

As I said, I believe its due to the fact that I am running on MacOS. Also FYI when I run this a blank tkinter window shows up with the update button, but no graph. The Graph DOES however show up in the regular text output but I want it in the tkinter window for a GUI. Please Help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the figure that is already in the tk canvas, instead of showing a new one with `plt.show()`. In this case there is only one figure open, so `plt.plot()` will actually work (although it might fail in more complex scenarios). What remains is to redraw the canvas, `fig.canvas.draw_idle()` after plotting.

```
import numpy as np
import Tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = tk.Tk()

fig = plt.figure(1)
t = np.arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
s = np.sin(np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t,s)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
plot_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()

def update():
    s = np.cos(np.pi*t)
    plt.plot(t,s)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

plot_widget.grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(root,text="Update",command=update).grid(row=1, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

For the future and to be on the save side, try to avoid using `pyplot` when embedding matplotlib into GUIs. This prevents you from having issues like the one reported here.

```
import numpy as np
import Tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = tk.Tk()

fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
t = np.arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
s = np.sin(np.pi*t)
ax.plot(t,s)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
plot_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()

def update():
    s = np.cos(np.pi*t)
    ax.plot(t,s)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

plot_widget.grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(root,text="Update",command=update).grid(row=1, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```